# [.data.table (merge - X[Y]) key got lost in v.1.9.3

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 data.tables `dtp` and `dtab`.

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dtp <- data.table(pid = gl(3, 3, labels = c("du", "i", "nouana")),
                  year = gl(3, 1, 9, labels = c("2007", "2010", "2012")),
                  val = rnorm(9), key = c("pid", "year"))
dtab <- data.table(pid = factor(c("i", "nouana")),
                  year = factor(c("2010", "2000")),
                  abn = sample(1:5, 2, replace = TRUE), key =
                   c("pid", "year"))
dtp
##       pid year        val
## 1:     du 2007 -0.6264538
## 2:     du 2010  0.1836433
## 3:     du 2012 -0.8356286
## 4:      i 2007  1.5952808
## 5:      i 2010  0.3295078
## 6:      i 2012 -0.8204684
## 7: nouana 2007  0.4874291
## 8: nouana 2010  0.7383247
## 9: nouana 2012  0.5757814

dtab
##       pid year abn
## 1:      i 2010   2
## 2: nouana 2000   4
```

If i merge them using `[.data.table`, the key get lost:

```
dtp[dtab]
##       pid year       val abn
## 1:      i 2010 0.3295078   2
## 2: nouana 2000        NA   4

key(dtp[dtab]) # key got lost
## NULL # v.1.9.3

##### which was in 1.8.10
## [1] "pid"  "year"
```

Ok, for this case I can set it manually:

```
res1 <- setkeyv(dtp[dtab], key(dtp))
res1
##       pid year       val abn
## 1:      i 2010 0.3295078   2
## 2: nouana 2000        NA   4

key(res1) # repaired it
## [1] "pid"  "year"
```

### Question:

Is this the wanted behaviour, or is it a bug?

### Alternative:

Using the `merge` syntax does what I expected:

```
merge(dtp, dtab, all.y = TRUE)
##       pid year       val abn
## 1:      i 2010 0.3295078   2
## 2: nouana 2000        NA   4

key(merge(dtp, dtab, all.y = TRUE)) # everything ok
## [1] "pid"  "year"
```

### Usage: add a column:

If I want to merge the column `abn` from `dtab` to `dtp` there is one easy possibility to write `dtab[dtp]` loosing the key and the order of the columns:

```
dtab[dtp]
##       pid year abn        val
## 1:     du 2007  NA -0.6264538
## 2:     du 2010  NA  0.1836433
## 3:     du 2012  NA -0.8356286
## 4:      i 2007  NA  1.5952808
## 5:      i 2010   2  0.3295078
## 6:      i 2012  NA -0.8204684
## 7: nouana 2007  NA  0.4874291
## 8: nouana 2010  NA  0.7383247
## 9: nouana 2012  NA  0.5757814
```

### Example how it could work

If there would be other cols in `dtab`, but just `abn` should be merged there is another possibility (my favourite):

```
##### just show it:
## dtp[dtab[dtp, abn]] # v.1.8.10

dtp[dtab[dtp, abn, by = .EACHI]] # since v.1.9.3
##       pid year        val abn
## 1:     du 2007 -0.6264538  NA
## 2:     du 2010  0.1836433  NA
## 3:     du 2012 -0.8356286  NA
## 4:      i 2007  1.5952808  NA
## 5:      i 2010  0.3295078   2
## 6:      i 2012 -0.8204684  NA
## 7: nouana 2007  0.4874291  NA
## 8: nouana 2010  0.7383247  NA
## 9: nouana 2012  0.5757814  NA
```

or assign it:

```
dtp[dtab[dtp], abn := abn] # assign it

dtp
##       pid year        val abn
## 1:     du 2007 -0.6264538  NA
## 2:     du 2010  0.1836433  NA
## 3:     du 2012 -0.8356286  NA
## 4:      i 2007  1.5952808  NA
## 5:      i 2010  0.3295078   2
## 6:      i 2012 -0.8204684  NA
## 7: nouana 2007  0.4874291  NA
## 8: nouana 2010  0.7383247  NA
## 9: nouana 2012  0.5757814  NA

key(dtp) # ok
## [1] "pid"  "year"
```

In latter cases (show or assign) the key survives.

@[Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559784/arun): Here is the `sessionInfo()`:

```
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
## Platform: powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

## other attached packages:
## [1] data.table_1.9.3

## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] plyr_1.8       reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2
```

Comment: Please post your `sessionInfo()` as well. Thanks.

Comment: Great post. Definitely a bug. It's happening on `factor` type key columns. Must've been a regression in 1.9.0+ if it seems to have worked in 1.8.10. Could you please post a bug report [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse)? Maybe title as "key is not retained after join on factor columns" and just link to this post in the body. You don't have to write the whole thing again. Thanks!

Comment: Correction: it works on 1.9.2 as well. It's just a bug recently introduced in 1.9.3.

Comment: Done. https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5659

Answer (score 2):

Now fixed in [`v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). Closes [#477](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/477). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 56. Key is retained properly when joining on factor type columns. Closes [#477](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/477). Thanks to @nachti for the report.

```
# v1.9.5+
key(dtp[dtab])
# [1] "pid"  "year"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in 1.9.3.  And was fixed in subsequent versions of data.table. See the comments under the question for a discussion.

Comment: Christopher, [it's not yet fixed](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/477), unfortunately :-(.